# Record counts of rows in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `abc` with the following columns :-

```
Table abc

name   emp_num     date        id
xyz        1    12/mar/2014   sail
xyt        2    12/mar/2014   sail
```

now I want to calculate total number of records but with `max` I am getting the record count as 1 but you can see in the above example there are two distinct records of `emp_num`. The columns I want to fetch is `date`,`id` and record count.
 the query I have used is :-

```
select date,id,count(*)

from abc
group by date,id;
```

output

```
  date        id    count(*)
    12/mar/2014   sail  1
    12/mar/2014   sail  1
```

This is retreiving two columns in which count is coming as 1

Comment: And how about posting a test case to prove what you say?

Comment: Your query should return count as 2.. are you sure you have this example right?

Comment: Can you post the data that you have there exactly and redact confidential information? With a table named `abc` and a basic query like yours, everybody who knows SQL grouping would know that query is supposed to work

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan i have edited the output as well

Comment: I don't know if you get what I'm saying.. The data you've provided doesn't seem to be the data you're having issue with.. If your schema looks similar to the snippet you've provided, it is supposed to work.. Take a look at this fiddle for example - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/795c5/2.. In other words, that is not the output that you'd get for that query

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is you're ignoring the time part of Oracle date-type. It's there even you don't see it.

Example:

```
create table foo(id number, date_ date);
insert into foo values(1, sysdate-1/1440);
insert into foo values(1, sysdate);
commit;

alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
select * from foo;

    ID DATE_
------ ----------
     1 2015-03-19
     1 2015-03-19

select id, date_, count(*)
from foo
group by id, date_;

    ID DATE_      COUNT(*)
------ ---------- ----------
     1 2015-03-19          1
     1 2015-03-19          1

alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
select * from foo;

    ID DATE_
------ -------------------
     1 2015-03-19 06:29:13
     1 2015-03-19 06:30:14

select id, date_, count(*)
from foo
group by id, date_;

    ID DATE_               COUNT(*)
------ ------------------- ----------
     1 2015-03-19 06:29:13          1
     1 2015-03-19 06:30:14          1
```